# SELECT COUNT in LINQ to SQL C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq

How can I write LINQ to SQL with COUNT?

Example:

```
var purch = from purchase in myBlaContext.purchases
            select purchase;
```

How can I get the count here?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Like that

```
var purchCount = (from purchase in myBlaContext.purchases select purchase).Count();
```

or even easier

```
var purchCount = myBlaContext.purchases.Count();
```

Comment: @Bside: `lblCount.Text = myBlaContext.purchases.Count().ToString()`

Comment: @George Duckett, thank you. but i got the error: CS0103: The name 'lblCount' does not exist in the current context ... and i put lblCount on the aspx page...

Comment: @Bside: Depending on where on the page you put it, you might not be able to access it like that. This is a seperate question really now: how to access a control on an asp.net page. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178509(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @Anrei Are there any performance differences if we use `myBlaContext.purchases.Count()` vs `(from purchase in myBlaContext.purchases select purchase.ID).Count()`

Comment: @irvgk, I suspect there might be. Actually you can use any sql profile you'd like to check the resulting sql query that linq generates, even for such similar queries it might differ. I will do that myself when I have a chance (not on windows at the moment)

Answer (score 10):

You should be able to do the count on the purch variable:

```
purch.Count();
```

e.g.

```
var purch = from purchase in myBlaContext.purchases
select purchase;

purch.Count();
```