# Find Count using lambda Expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have following classes:

```
public class Promotion
{
    public Offers Offers { get; set; }
}
public class Offers
{
   public List<PromotionOffer> Offer { get; set; }
}

public class PromotionOffer
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

And I have an object of `Promotion`:

```
Promotion applicablePromotion = promotion;
```

`applicablePromotion` contains list of  `Offer` and each offer has `CategoryName`. I want to find count where `CategoryName == Package`

Something like:

```
int count = applicablePromotion.Offers.Offer.Find(c => c.CategoryName == "Package").Count;
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What have your tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SELECT COUNT in LINQ to SQL C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330682/select-count-in-linq-to-sql-c-sharp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use:

```
var count = applicablePromotion.Offers.Offer.Count(o => o.CategoryName == "Package");
```

In LINQ the `Count` can accept a Lambda expression and you don't have to query with `Where`

Check it out here:

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="475" src="https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/UKyWQJ" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Where` instead of `Find`:

```
int count = applicablePromotion.Offers
       .Offer
       .Where(x=> x.CategoryName == "Package")
       .Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be only:

```
int count = applicablePromotion.Offers.Find(c => c.CategoryName == "Package").Count;
```

I suppose `Offers` is your collection here, so you have to run Find on that.

Comment: The Property `Offers` on the `Promotion` is not a collection but it contains the collection.

Comment: I yes, sorry I see. The naming was a little bit confusing for me. The original code then should just work fine I think. What is the probpem with it? What is the error message when we try to use it?